# Solving : Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation

Tags: vb.net, web-services, iis

I have two systems, one is sending large amount of data (about 1GB) through web service. First it splits the data into chunks, then send it to the client when requested with extra information.

The data is not sent as byte array directly, but instead is placed into a special class i created that has two members:

1) Message : i use it specify what to do with the chunk
2) Obj     : a byte array representing the data

So basically the server fills this structure then it serialize the whole object, and finally send it to the client. Each chunk is about 4KB

Again this is repeated many times, so the amount of data transmission could be 1GB or 2GB. When I try to run this i get this error:

**System.InsufficientMemoryException was caught
  Message="Insufficient winsock resources available to complete socket connection initiation."**

When I tried: **netstat -an -p TCP**

I got something like this...

TCP    127.0.0.1:58759        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:58760        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:58761        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:58762        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:58763        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:58764        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:58765        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:58766        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

...

increasing up to about:

...

TCP    127.0.0.1:65531        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:65532        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

TCP    127.0.0.1:65533        127.0.0.1:57469        TIME_WAIT

There should be a hot fix for this - in a previous answer but it did not work. The hot fix is here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2577795

I used similar code before, but instead of doing serialization, I just sent the data as array of bytes directly, and it worked perfectly fine. I find no difference between the codes except for the use of the encapsulation class I created and the serialization process.

Could anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

thank you.

===========================================

I found a simple way to replicate this issue:

Start by creating a VB.NET webservice that has the following method:

```
<WebMethod(enablesession:=False)> _
Public Function HelloWorld() As Byte()
    Dim B(0 To 1000) As Byte
    Return B
End Function
```

Next create a client for it as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim T As New ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient
    T.Open()
    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 0 To 1000000
        T.HelloWorld()
        Me.Text = I
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next
End Sub
```

you will get this error. Hope someone has a solution for this.

Comment: Hmm maybe you send new packets to server but server can't get them because of internet speed? Do you check if previous packet reached server before sending new packets (e.g. server sends a little message indicating that previous packet was accepted)?

Answer (score 0):

Try closing/disposing the client between calls.

`For I as Integer = 0 To 1000000
        Using T As New ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient
           T.Open()
           T.HelloWorld()
           Me.Text = I
        End Using
        Application.DoEvents()
    Next`

Comment: Not sure if that class implements IDisposable. If not use the .Close() method.